# How to remove an element from set using Iterator?

Tags: java, iterator, set, hashset

I have a scenario that I am iterating over a set using iterator. Now I want to remove 1st element while my iterator is on 2nd element. How can I do it. I know Set is unordered and there is nothing like first or second element but my question is I want to remove an element which is not being currently returned by Iterator.next

1. I dont want to convert this set to list and using listIterator.
2. I dont want to collect all objects to be removed in other set and call remove all
3. I cant store it and remove after the iteration

sample code.

```
Set<MyObject> mySet = new HashSet<MyObject>();

mySet.add(MyObject1);
mySet.add(MyObject2);

...
Iterator itr = mySet.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
            // Now iterator is at second element and I want to remove first element
        }
```

Comment: You cannot modify a collection while you are iterating it.

Comment: We can modify using iterator

Comment: I don't know how this should work - with Java 8, you can call `removeIf` on a collection, but you don't get a reference to the last element either. I guess you need a double linked list or something like that, because a `Set` has no order by definition.

Comment: @ankit I have wriiteen a code to remove perceived 1st element without using Iterator's remove method or removeall

Comment: @ankit I suggest you use a LinkedHashSet

Comment: @Darshan Lila: can you explain (proof) you statement? Do you mean all kinds of modification or only those ones except Iterator.remove() method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the constraints as you have stated them, I don't think that there is solution to the problem.

- The `Iterator.remove()` method will only remove the "current" element.
- You have excluded "remembering" objects and removing them from the `HashSet` in a second pass / phase.
- Schemes that involve using two iterators simultaneously and removing using one of them will result in CCMEs on the second one.

The three approaches that you suggested (but then excluded) would all work. I think the 2nd one would be the most performant.

Another idea would be to implement a new hash table-based `Set` type which has an `Iterator` with an extra remove operation.  (You could start with the source code of `HashSet` etcetera, rename the class and then modify it to do what you need.)

Answer (score 0):

HashSet is unordered and javadoc clearly states that **Iterator's remove** method *`Removes from the underlying collection the last element returned by this iterator (optional operation).`* So the answer is no through an iterator.Since HashSet contains unique elements,you can use Set.remove(Object) after traversing the first element,in thios case you dont even need to go to the 2nd element

```
HashSet<K> hs;// you HashSet containing unique elements

if(!hs.isEmpty())
{
  hs.remove(hs.iterator().next());
}
```

**`Just remember HashSet is unordered and there is no such thing as 1st or 2nd element`**

***Alternately,you should use `LinkedHashSet` which gives you an ordered Set based on insertion order***

Comment: This can be any inserted element, right? It will remove whichever element the Iterator returns first.

Comment: @Magnilex Precisely yes..HashSet is unordered,there is no ordering of elements.OP states whatever 1st element returned by the iterator

Comment: Ok, OP has clarified the question. Given his requirements, I would say that it is not possible. This answer will anyway just unpredictably remove an element.

Comment: @Magnilex I answered the OP. hs.remove(hs.iterator().next()); does the trick

Comment: @Magnilex I suggest the OP use LinkedHashet ,it gives an ordered Set based on insertion order

Answer (score 0):

`Set.iterator()` returns a `java.lang.Iterator`. This iterator only provides methods to remove the *current* element and to iterate *forward*.

So if you don't want to convert your set, using only `Iterator` you cannot remove the previous element.

What you can do for example is that you collect the elements you want to remove, and after you iterated through the whole set, you remove the collected elements after, e.g. with `Set.removeAll(removableCollection)`:

```
List<MyObject> removableList = new ArrayList<>();

MyObject previous;

Iterator<MyObject> itr = mySet.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    MyObject current = itr.next();

    // If you find you want to remove the previous element:
    if (someCondition)
        removableList.add(previous);

    previous = current;
}

mySet.removeAll(removeableList);
```

Comment: I have mentioned this in my question that I dont want to do a remove all

Comment: And I have mentioned that you cannot do what you want with simply using the `Iterator`.

Comment: I know this but my current scenario does not allow me to do all these things and I cant paste my actual code here

Comment: Then your current scenario makes it impossible to do what you want to do.